# Conditionally disable ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the best way to disable ASP.NET MVC controller conditionally?

I want to have an access to the controller actions if some value in web.config is "true" and 404 if it's "false"

Should I write my own attribute?

**UPDATE**:
Looking for more elegant solution than action filter attribute (with an ability to pass not constant parameter to attribute constructor)

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public class CloseForSomeSettingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            bool mySettingValue = MySettingManager.GetMySettingValue();

            if (mySettingValue)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(404);
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to implement a custom action filter:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

You can also conditionally add a route that matches that controller that would result in a 404 being returned.

Comment: thanks. have written the action filter attribute (see my comment). but maybe some more elegant solution exists?

Comment: I don't know your purpose here but perhaps it's best not to do this at the application level? I'm thinking using IIS url-rewrite module to setup rules for the routes you're looking to return 404. Take a look at the examples below:http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2009/04/08/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks.aspx

Comment: no. I need to have an ability to switch it from a web.config file.

Comment: the rules for url-rewrite are stored in the web.config

Answer (score 3):

Answered here - [Prevent ASP.NET Core discovering Controller in separate assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64789567/prevent-asp-net-core-discovering-controller-in-separate-assembly)

This approach doesn't need filters, and hides controller from swagger etc.

Answer (score 0):

Cross posting from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43044667/257470

My solution for disabling `ApiController` controller:

- Uses WebConfig AppSettings config flag instead of (`#if DEBUG`)
- Before method is invoked `ExecuteAsync` intercepts the invocation and checks feature toggle (feature flag);
- if feature is disabled, returns `HTTP 410 GONE`
- If it's common for many controllers, move the code to controller's base class

The code:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var featureFlag = Convert.ToBoolean(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableTest"]);

        if (featureFlag == false)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Gone));
        }

        return base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
    }
```