# Prevent ASP.NET Core discovering Controller in separate assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I've got an ASP.NET Core API that references a nuget package that contains a `Controller`.

By default, this controller is registered and can respond to requests. However, I only want to add this in certain circumstances - e.g. if it's in the DEV environment.

My `Startup` looks like this:

```
services.AddControllers()
.AddMvcOptions(cfg => {
   cfg.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilterAttribute())
});
```

I expected I'd need to call `AddApplicationPart(typeof(ClassInPackage).Assembly)` after calling `AddCointrollers` to register this controller?

Can someone advise a way I can enable / disable the registration of this controller?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally disable ASP.NET MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604773/conditionally-disable-asp-net-mvc-controller)

Comment: @DavidEdel it would prevent the execution of the action methods, but the endpoints would still be visible on swagger etc, so ideally we could hide it there too..

Comment: If conditional directive like this   #if DEBUG
  .....
#endif can help you? You can  use attribute routes with it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution - remove the `ApplicationPart` that contains the `Controller`. Any other dependencies in the assembly can still be used.

In Startup.cs / wherever you do your IoC:

```
if(hideControllerFromOtherAssembly)
{
   var appPartManager = (ApplicationPartManager)services.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ServiceType == typeof(ApplicationPartManager)).ImplementationInstance;
   var mockingPart = appPartManager.ApplicationParts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "MyMockLibrary.Namespace");

   if(mockingPart != null)
   {
      appPartManager.ApplicationParts.Remove(mockingPart);
   }
}
```

You can also manipulate `ApplicationParts` via the extension method:

```
AddMvc().ConfigureApplicationPartManager()
```

This wasn't suitable for me as I'd written an extension method in my nuget package

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Just a side-note. Just imaging someone has authored many controllers that are high customizable. You are a user of library of such controllers. You are picky and does not want to have all controllers. Do you really want to remove all controller by hand AS CUSTOMER?????